# black screen when loading html from text editor

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm new to programming. I have purchased a book *Beginning Javascript 4th edition* and I began working with an example on my text editor 2013. I've changed the preferences on text editor to "plain text" and "display as html." I wrote the example code out and tried to load it onto Google Chrome; however, all I am getting is a black screen. Can anyone help? This is my code:

```
<html> 
<body bgcolor=“WHITE”>
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<script type=“text/javascript”>
    document.bgColor = “RED”;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I should be getting a red screen with text "Paragraph 1" in the top-left corner of the page.

Comment: how did you try to "load it onto google chrome"?

Comment: The bgcolor attribute is not supported in html5, use css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemed to have used the wrong quotes in a couple of places -

```
bgcolor=“WHITE”>
        ^     ^
```

Replacing them with the correct quotes will render it properly.

Try copy pasting and running this block -

```
<html> 
<body bgcolor="WHITE">
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<script type="  text/javascript">
    document.bgColor = "RED";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this will work, but using CSS is the right way to do this in context of html5.

Comment: @Zee yep, you're right, but that was not the problem. It will render bgcolor anyway. And secondly as the OP states, he is learning it from a javascript book and I assume he is copy pasting code to see what happens.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. That did render it perfectly. I thought I just wasn't meant to code! Haha, thanks again all!